# How to resolve Creating default object from empty value in laravel-8?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-blade

I am working with blade templates in laravel and i passed the dummy data to the .blade.php file but while hitting that api it's throwing an following error can you please help me to resolve the issue..?

```
ErrorException
Creating default object from empty value
http://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

**UserController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function GetUsers(){
        return view('users')->with(
                                    [$this->session->flashdata ='gs'],
                                    ['userslist' =>['id'=>'1','name'=>'dummy_text']]
                                   );
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `$this->session->flashdata ='gs'`? Which line is actually causing the error?

Comment: Can you please share a blade view file? In view file, are you using $userslist-> id? if yes then you need to use it like $userslist['id'].